# How to do I deploy a Spring app using Postgresql to Heroku using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, heroku, spring-4

I am evaluating Spring 4 on Heroku and I am so far very impressed with both.

However, I am having trouble getting my Spring Boot app to run on Heroku.  Everything is working fine, except Postgresql (I just get `Connection Refused` errors).

The problem will surely be to do with how I am setting up the `DataSource` but so far I've just been following a trial and error approach! I am not exactly sure how I am supposed to set-up the data source from the Heroku `DATABASE_URL` and I can't find any examples.

I have found [spring-cloud](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud) by chance by searching on Google which looks promising but it doesn't explained anything about the `DATABASE_URL`.  Also, it isn't even mentioned on Spring.IO so I am wondering if it is even an option for production use?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Spring Cloud is a good option. I don't know why it's not listed in spring.io - it should be, maybe it isn't quite out of incubation yet or something, but I have used it successfully. If you don't like using that I think you can probably just set the `spring.datasource.url` to the value Heroku gives you in its env var.

Comment: Could you provide some information on how you set-up the datasource in spring-cloud? Where do you specify the DATABASE_URL for instance?

Comment: Cloudfoundry example here: https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/blob/master/sagan-common/src/main/java/sagan/DatabaseConfig.java. The code would be the same for Heroku (which is the point of Spring Cloud), i.e. you don't need to know the URL.

Comment: Does anyone have a complete project Heroku example?

Comment: @SARose I've pust together a blog post with featuring a little sample application: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/10/deploying-spring-boot-applications-to-heroku/

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) which can be configured in the settings tab of your application at Heroku. The Config Vars will be exposed as environment variables to your application. Since Spring Boot can map environment variables to application properties you just need to set:

```
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
SPRING_DATASOURCE_USER
SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME
```

And they will be mapped to:

```
spring.datasource.url
spring.datasource.user
spring.datasource.password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name
```

Now all you have to do is to extract the relevant values. The complete data base configuration can be inspected at the [heroku postgres management panel](https://postgres.heroku.com/databases/). Select the data base you want to connect to and you will see the values for `SPRING_DATASOURCE_USER` and `SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD` right away. The `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` has to be constructed like this:

`jdbc:postgresql://<Host>:<Port>/<Database>`

Where `<Host>`, `<Port>` and `<Database>`have to replaced by the corresponding values from the data base connection page. Last but not least the `SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME` has to be set to `org.postgresql.Driver`.

This way you can use the build in functionality of Spring Boot instead of adding environment specific configuration to your application. Note however, that Spring Boot has a specific [order of reading external configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). So you have to make sure there are no

- Command line arguments (passed via the [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile))
- JNDI attributes from java:comp/env (don't know where those might be coming from in Heroku.)
- Java System properties (can also be passed via the Procfile as `-D` arguments)

since those would override the OS environment variables.

Comment: `SPRING_DATASOURCE_USER`  didn't work for me but `SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME` works,

Answer (score 2):

One thing I would like to add after struggling with this for a while - just creating a configuration object is not sufficient with Heroku, even with the spring cloud connectors.  You also have to explicitly declare the cloud profile (`-Dspring.profiles.active=cloud`) in your application Procfile.

Comment: Could you show your Procfile and you java files so we can see how this works please?

Answer (score 2):

Apart from `DATABASE_URL`, which is always there, Heroku creates 3 environment variables at Runtime. They are:

```
JDBC_DATABASE_URL
JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME
JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD
```

As you may be aware, Spring Boot will automatically configure your database if it finds `spring.datasource.*` properties in your `application.properties` file. Here is an example of my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

**Hibernate / Postgres Dependencies**

In my case I'm using Hibernate (bundled in `spring-boot-starter-jpa` with PostgreSQL, so I needed the right dependencies in my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile('org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1212')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I remember right, I had the same problem and reading through the Heroku Postgres documentation I found that I needed to specify two extra connection properties for the DataSource.

I had to configure the following properties:

- **ssl=true**
- **sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory**

Here's an example of a DataSource bean:

```
   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    <property name="connectionProperties" value="ssl=true;sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory"/>
</bean>
```

You of course need to add a [PostgreSql](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql) library dependency.